# How to fetch data that looks like "0: data: testdata1 1: data: testdata2" in nextjs

Tags: api, next.js

so I want to fetch data with promp and show it to a nextjs components

The data respon looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sp24i.png

I don't know how to fetch data with promp that looks like that, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Nvm, i found it with this code:

```js
const data = await db.collection("myCollection").find({ "myFiled": "myValue" }).toArray();
```

Comment: Instead of providing the answer directly, try writing a comment explaining the solution if it's not too lengthy. @ZenZoyaUDR.